# Can I open vim with scrollbind already set?

Tags: vim

I know to use -O to open (g)vim with vertical buffers. Since I do this a lot, I'd like to save some steps by presetting scrollbind and syncbind, but I can't find any documentation that this can be done. Has anyone managed to do so?

Comment: Have you tried putting it in your `.vimrc` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `scrollbind` using the `-c` flag and `windo`:

```
vim -O file1 file2 -c "windo set scrollbind"
```

The result is that both windows have `scrollbind` set.

A side effect is that the cursor will end up in the last window.  To combat that you could run a second command after it to jump to the top-most left-most window:

```
vim -O file1 file2 -c "windo set scrollbind" -c "wincmd t"
```

Comment: That's perfect -- and I don't mind the cursor being in the second window. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to tack syncbind on as well?

Comment: I can't test right now but I think you can set multiple options at once. Try just tacking it on after the scrollbind.